# Binding triggered actions to functions without subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

For analytic purposes, I would like to do the following:

- When a `UIVIewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` is triggered, I would like to trigger a custom function `vcWasLoaded(vc:UIViewController)`.
- Similarly, when a `UIButton` is tapped, I would like to trigger a custom function `btnWasTapped(bt:UIButton)`.

I would like to achieve the above without subclasses. Anyway to achieve the above using protocols, extensions, or reactive frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method swizzling is the only thing I can think of that you could use that would let you do this without subclassing. You'd replace the implementation of viewDidLoad, and one of the lower-level button methods, and then call the original implementation in yours. (I've only dabbled in method swizzling, and it was many years ago, before Swift existed. I don't know much about Objective-C method swizzling, and know exactly **zero** about method swizzling in Swift.)

This would be much simpler and cleaner if you created a subclass of UIViewController and made it the base class of all of your view controllers.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! That is what I will do.